# change the speed of setInterval in the second round

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to change the speed of the interval for calling a function.

The first time it should take a second, and the rest should take nine seconds to call.

```
var tiempoCaratula=1000;    
var refreshCaratula = setInterval(function() {   
  $('.col-2').load('caratula.php'); 
}, tiempoCaratula);
```

Comment: what do you need to do? run the function one second after `load` finishes its job?

Comment: I need the first interval lasts 1 second and from there it always lasts 9 seconds

Comment: That will call `$('.col-2').load('caratula.php');` every 1000ms or 1 second. `$('.col-2').load('caratula.php');` Could be taking longer than that to execute though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the first one using `setTimeout` and then schedule it for future runs in whatever interval you need to.

```
var myFunction = function() {
  $('.col-2').load('caratula.php'); 
}

var refreshCaratula;

// call the function after 1000ms
setTimeout(function () {
  myFunction();
  // then schedule it to run every 9000ms
  refreshCaratula = setInterval(myFunction, 9000);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a timeout that runs once at one second and a sub interval that runs every nine seconds after the timeout.

```
var tiempoCaratula = 1000;
var tiempoCaratula2 = 9000;
var refreshCaratula = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.col-2').load('caratula.php'); 

    var refreshCaratula2 = setInterval(function() {
        $('.col-2').load('caratula.php'); 

    }, tiempoCaratula2);

}, tiempoCaratula);
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works, sensational !! Thank you so much for everything.